# Integral of a function over a ball of radius tending to zero

Tags: analysis

If it is true, can anyone give me a rigorous proof for the second equality?

for $w$ any continuous function defined on a locally compact metric space $(X,d)$,

for $B[x,r]$ the ball whith center $x$ and radius $r$.

Thank you in advance.

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{B(x,r)} w \, d\mu = \lim_{r \to 0} \int_{B(x,r)} w \chi(B(x,r)) \, d\mu =\\ \lim_{r \to 0} \int_{B(x,r)} w(x) \chi(B(x,r)) \, d\mu = \\ w(x)\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{B(x,r)}  \chi(B(x,r)) \, d\mu$$

Comment: Please format using MathJax, not Mathematica code.

Answer (score 1):

You need Lebesgue differentiation theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ be an $L^1$ function. Then, for almost every $x$, we have, $$ \lim_{r\to 0}
> \cfrac{1}{\mu(B(x, r))} \int_{B(x, r)} f(y) dy = f(x). $$

See Tao's *'An Introduction to Measure Theory'*, Theorem 1.6.19.

(Actually you can relax the $L^1$ requirement to $L^1_{loc}$.)

Comment: I edited the question, I need f defined on a generic locally compact metric space. Is this theorem still applicable here?

Comment: @JhonnyAnnunci You need a measure to integrate. I am not aware if Lebesgue differentiation theorem holds for abstract measures.

Comment: @JhonnyAnnunci It holds for locally compact ultrametric spaces. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem#Discussion